# Create own .cls with vertical border text based on section

Tags: document-classes, rotating

Ive got kind of a special request today.

I would like to define my own latex template (.cls). There should be

- the same vertical text on the right/left page border based on the section/chapter
- multicolumn for each page
- no pagenumbers at all (and loosing of the header line as showed in the example

The following code shows what I have created so far. As you might guess this is supposed to be some kind of restaurant.

```
\ProvidesClass{menuX}[2018/03/09, v1, menuX, foo]


\LoadClass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{twoside}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[paperheight=28cm, paperwidth=14cm,%
                top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2cm,%
%               showframe
                ]{geometry}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}
\RequirePackage{tikz-page}
\pagestyle{plain}

\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\grey}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{.66 .66 .66}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tikzpagelayout}{
    \node[ rotate=90, below](t) at (page.west) {\fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont \grey {testBorderPage}};
}
```

Using this, I can provide an example code like..

```
\documentclass{menuX}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
    Hello World!
    \clearpage
    Hello again
\end{document}
```

I hope this is telling what I would like to do. This is all more or less some kind of workaround since I got some experience with latex, but non at all creating my on template.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty}` if you want to eliminate the page number as well as everything else? Maybe look at `flowfram` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially since you are already using `scrartcl`, you can create pagestyles like this with `scrlayer`: You create two layers, one at the left and one at the right margin, each with your vertical text.
Then you can create a pagestyle containing only theses two layers.

```
\ProvidesClass{menuX}[2018/03/09, v1, menuX, foo]

\LoadClass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{twocolumn,twoside}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[paperheight=28cm, paperwidth=14cm,%
                top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,%
                ]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{scrlayer}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\grey}[1]{\textcolor[gray]{.66}{#1}}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  everypage,
  leftmargin,
  contents={%
    \vfil\hfil\rotatebox{90}{%
      \fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont\grey\leftmark%
    }\hfil\vfil
}]{markmargin-left}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  everypage,
  rightmargin,
  contents={%
    \vfil\hfil\rotatebox{90}{%
      \fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont\grey\rightmark%
    }\hfil\vfil
}]{markmargin-right}

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{markmargin}{markmargin-right,markmargin-left}
\pagestyle{markmargin}
\automark[section]{section}
```

The output for this example document:

```
\documentclass{menuX}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\addsec{First}
  \lipsum
  \clearpage
\addsec{Second}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

**EDIT**: If you don't want the section headers, you can avoid adding sections in the first place:
If instead of

```
\automark[section]{section}
```

you write

```
\manualmark
\renewcommand\section[1]{%
  \clearpage%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
}
```

the command `\section{Some name}` will start a new page and update the margins, but not do anything else, especially no section title will be printed.
Of course, then you have to use `\section` instead of `\addsec` in the example.

Comment: Wooh. Thank you very much. I will try to figure out what your code is meaning in specific. Can you help me with `\vfill\hfill`?
Also I wonder, if I am able to skip the section headline at all, but keep displaying subsections? If necessary I could switch to report and chapters

Comment: `\vfill\hfill` is an infinite stretchable vertical space followed by an infinite stretchable horizontal space. The space is evenly distributed between the `\vfill\hfill` before the content and the `\hfill\vfill` after the content, so both horizontal and vertical space are in same parts before and after the content. The is a quite complicated way to say: The title is centered horizontally an d vertically.

Comment: You can see that this isn't true in the screenshot, thats because I used `\vfil` instead of `\vfill`. `\vfil` is a smaller infinity and there is a implicit `\vfil` at the end, so the vertical space is split between one `\vfil` at the top and two `\vfil` at the bottom, so the space at the top has half the size of the bottom space.

Comment: Thanks again. As well for the edit. But when using your suggested do-over I receive an error.
" You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode."

Comment: In the EDIT, the `#2` should be a `#1`.(Sorry!) Please try this change, but that should have caused another error message...

Comment: hmm...dont know. Works pretty well with your fix.